# Custom geo map points not working in highmap

Tags: charts, highcharts, geomap

I created a custom geo map for US region with two states highlighted geojson data. US base map and highlighted states worked.

But i am not able to point US capitals using another set of geoJson data for US Capitals. Same way I am trying to add few bubbles on different locations in the US MAP. But both points and bubbles are not working in the MAP.

What am i missing to display mappoints and mapbubbles from geojson data?

JS fiddle is https://jsfiddle.net/s9mqcefp/300/

```
chart = Highcharts.mapChart('container', {
    title: {
        text: 'Highmaps lat/lon demo'
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Basemap',
        mapData: usStates,
        borderColor: '#606060',
        nullColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.2)',
        showInLegend: true
    },
    {
        name: 'Highlighted',
        mapData: usStatesHighLight,
        type:'map',
        borderColor: '#ff0000',
        nullColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[7], //'rgba(200, 0,0, 0.2)',
        showInLegend: true,
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[7]

    }, {
        type: 'mappoint',
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            format: 'Capital',
            allowOverlap: true
        },
        name: 'Capitals',
        mapData: usCapitals,
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[5]
    },
            {
        type: 'mapbubble',
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            format: 'State',
            allowOverlap: true
        },
        name: 'Radius/Region',
        mapData: radiusData,
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[3]
    }
   ]
});
```

Comment: Hi CrazyProgrammer, you have to adapt to the Highcharts data structure. Series `mappoint` and `mapbubble` require `data` property, but your map does not support latitude/longitude, which causes Highcharts Error #22: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/az3xpykf/

Comment: I got it working here is the example jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/varghees/s9mqcefp/375/